# Zbots not working with Counter-Strike 1.6 steam version

Tags: steam, counter-strike

I recently bought Counter-Strike 1.6 on Steam. Now I can't find the cstrike/maps sub folder, don´t know where the maps are saved and the [zbots](http://www.fileplanet.com/182178/180000/fileinfo/Counter-Strike-1.6---Z-Bot) are analyzing, restarting, analyzing, restarting... and so on. Is anyone having the same problems?

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zBot is a bot system that got basically ripped from Condition Zero, and AFAIK doesn't want to work with Steam version of CS 1.6.

I personally use [PodBot](http://podbotmm.bots-united.com/main_pb_page/downloads.htm) - this has always worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This version of zBot http://cs.gamebanana.com/tools/5054 works on the Steam distribution of CS however you need to install Metamod first: http://metamod.org/metamod.html